# How to install JUnit5 with Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, junit, dsl

So, I've been trying to add the JUnit5 dependency for my Kotlin project, however when I try to insert

```
tasks.test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
   testLogging {
       events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
   }
}
```

The intelliJ gives the error 'unresolved reference test'. The gradle version is 4.8. I really don't know what to do! I tried to do exactly by the example project: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.6.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle-kotlin/build.gradle.kts but it just doesn't work. I have been trying for hours...

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of Gradle (the latest version is 6.5.1)?

Comment: @Slaw If I get the [changelog](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/releases) right, accessing tasks directly by their name from `tasks` is possible since the Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0 RC1, which was released with Gradle 4.10 RC1. This would mean, that the above code cannot work using Gradle 4.8.

Answer (score 1):

As many have suggested, to get the following syntax working you should update Gradle to the latest version:

```kotlin
tasks.test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
   testLogging {
       events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
   }
}
```

However, here's a working example for older Gradle versions in case you can't upgrade:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: At least use `named<Test>("test")` instead of just `withType<Test>` to just configure the task named `test`.

Comment: @rafapili1 feel free to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: @rafapili1 I would still suggest updating Gradle; version 4.8 is _old_.